# Express: Issue with async request handler

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I'm running following code on express :

```
app.get('/items/:item', async function (req, res) {
  let itemName = req.params.itemName;
  let item = new DataItem(itemName);
  let itemProcessed = await item.process(); //call of async method 
  console.log(itemProcessed); //prints data processed 
  res.json(itemProcessed);
})
```

I see that response was not sent.
Also I can see that itemProcessed string representation was printed with console.log
If I remove async staff from the function ( async prefix and call of some async method ) - the response was sent

Is there something missing ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds weird. Can you please share the implementation of `DataItem`'s `process` function?

Comment: `class DataItem {  
async process() {   
let dataRead = await this.getSomeDataFromWeb(); //with fetch
this.fillByDataRead(dataRead);  
return this;  
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use `express-async-wrap` package in order to use `async` handlers:

```
const wrap = require('express-async-wrap')


app.get('/items/:item', wrap(async function (req, res) {
  let itemName = req.params.itemName;
  let item = new DataItem(itemName);
  let itemProcessed = await item.process(); //call of async method 
  console.log(itemProcessed); //prints data processed 
  res.json(itemProcessed);
})
```